# The url is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The link of this url is not working , I am using bootstrap for dropdown.

```
<a data-target="#" href="washington-record-sealing/" role="button"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Record Sealing <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: when clicking the link it's showing the dropdown but couldn't enter the link.I want to make a dropdown like this link-http://washington-expungement.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you looking for these.

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #ec4445;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active, a:hover {
    outline: 0 none;
}

ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}


.main-menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.main-menu ul li a {
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-menu > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #83cbdc;
}

.main-menu ul li::before {
    background: #ddd none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 1px;
}

.main-menu ul li ul {
    background: #393939 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 160%;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li:before {
    display: none;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li {
    float: none;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li a {
    color: #9e9e9e;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.main-menu ul li ul li:hover a {
    color: #5eb4dc;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.main-menu ul li .mega-menu {
    background: #393939;
    left: 0;
    width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}

.main-menu ul li:hover .mega-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
}

.main-menu ul li .mega-menu span {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}

.main-menu ul li .mega-menu span a {
    color: #9e9e9e;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 25px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.main-menu ul li .mega-menu span a:hover {
    color: #6cc6d6;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.main-menu ul li .mega-menu span a.mega-title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-menu ul li .mega-menu span a.mega-title:hover {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <div class="main-menu">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">home <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">home version 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">home version 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">home version 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">home version 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">home version 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">home version 1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="#">mega menu <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                <div class="mega-menu">
                                    <span>
                                        <a class="mega-title" href="#">Mega title</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 1</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 2</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 3</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 4</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 5</a>
                                    </span>
                                    <span>
                                        <a class="mega-title" href="#">Mega title</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 1</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 2</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 3</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 4</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 5</a>
                                    </span>
                                    <span>
                                        <a class="mega-title" href="#">Mega title</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 1</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 2</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 3</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 4</a>
                                        <a href="#">Mega item 5</a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">work <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">shop <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">blog <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">blog page 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">blog page 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">blog page 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">blog page 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">blog page 1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">contact <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. but sorry I am not looking this . http://higbee.codeperpixels.com/             and    http://washington-expungement.com/     last link is client what asking for ...i tried but it's not working for mobile version. when dropdown appare then the link of the parent menu is not working.

Comment: Hey dude you could use (https://github.com/meanthemes/meanMenu) these plugin for mobile menu  :)